# angular page architecture for additional table

Tags: angularjs

I have an existing page logic that i need to extend.
i have a page displaying a table and a refresh button to reload page data from server (one controller and one service).

I want to to add 2 buttons to the page, one to display the existing table data and a new one that will display a similar table with different data.
refresh button needs to refresh current table data.
the user need to be able to switch between the buttons and see the relevent table.
each table will display a loader while data is loading.

for now i've created two partial html one for each table data (they contain part of the same column names)
I included the partials in the main html (display controlled by flags bound to the button chosen)
but all logic is under one controller and one model.

It seems it isn't the best solution and i will have a lot of variables in my scope.
one for each table data and additional flags (one for controlling the loader of each table etc..)

what would be a better way to extend the logic? 
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like [How to build a full dynamic template in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596658/how-to-build-a-full-dynamic-template-in-angular/39600113#39600113)

and handle switch logic in controller. In controller you'll need just change config and data variables, and manage single isLoading flag.